# Оценить код, Может как-то улучшить

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Ребят, не оценивайте верстку и адаптивность. Главное - js код, а именно фильтрация
https://github.com/RomeoC0der/ProductFilter - ссылка на сурс
Я beginner и буду рад критике

```js
let samsung = document.getElementById('Samsung');
let xiaomi = document.getElementById('Xiaomi');
let apple = document.getElementById('Apple');

let filter = data =>
{
 var dat = data.getAttribute('data');
 var checkbox = data;
 if(dat.toLowerCase() == 'samsung')
 {
  if(checkbox.checked == true)
  {
   samsung.style.display = "flex";
  }
  else
  {
  samsung.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
 if(dat.toLowerCase() == 'xiaomi')
 {
  if(checkbox.checked == true)
  {
    xiaomi.style.display = "flex";
  }
  else
  {
    xiaomi.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
 if(dat.toLowerCase() == 'apple')
 {
  if(checkbox.checked == true)
  {
    apple.style.display = "flex";
  }
  else
  {
    apple.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}
function ramFilter(ram)
{
let VofRAM = ram.getAttribute('RAMS');
let allSmarts = document.querySelectorAll('[ram=\''+VofRAM+'\']');
 if(ram.checked == true)
 {
  for(let i = 0; i < allSmarts.length; i++)
  {
   allSmarts[i].style.display = "flex";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  for(let i = 0; i < allSmarts.length; i++)
  {
   allSmarts[i].style.display = "none";
  }

 }
}

function romFilter(rom)
{
let VofROM = rom.getAttribute('ROMS');
let allSmarts = document.querySelectorAll('[rom=\''+VofROM+'\']');
 if(rom.checked == true)
 {
  for(let i = 0; i < allSmarts.length; i++)
  {
   allSmarts[i].style.display = "flex";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  for(let i = 0; i < allSmarts.length; i++)
  {
   allSmarts[i].style.display = "none";
  }

 }
}
```

```css
body
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
*
{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

{
 padding: 2px !important;
 margin: 2px !important;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.container
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 20vh;
}
.container-first-column
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: row;
 width: 100%;

}
.container-first-column img
{
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 300px;
}
.container-second-column img
{
width: 100%;
 max-width: 300px;
}
.container-third-column img
{
width: 100%;
 max-width: 300px;
}
.container-second-column
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: row;
 width: 100%;
}
.container-third-column
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: row;
 width: 100%;
}
.container-first-column-row
{
 width: 30%;
 padding: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px  pink;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.container-second-column-row
{
 width: 30%;
 margin-top: 2vh;
 padding: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px  pink;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.container-third-column-row
{
 width: 30%;
 margin-top: 2vh;
 padding: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px  pink;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.icon
{
 max-width: 100% !important;
 width: 1rem !important;
 padding: 1px !important;
 margin: 5px !important;
}
button
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
/*
@media (max-width: 1454px)
{
 h2{
  font-size: 1.3em;
 }
 p{
  font-size: 1em;
 }
}
@media(max-width: 1230px)
{
 h2{
  font-size: 1.1em;
 }
 p{
  font-size: 0.85em;
 }
}
@media(max-width: 1050px)
{
 h2{
  font-size: 0.9em;
 }
 p{
  font-size: 0.75em;
 }
}
*/
.filter
{
 display: flex;
 width: 10%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: gray;
 flex-direction: column;
 
 align-items: center;
 margin-top: 20vh;
}
.filter-body
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.filter-body div
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: row;
}
input
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.main
{
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 flex-direction: row;
}
.filter
{
 transform: translateX(-100%);
 transition: all .5s;
}

#openFilter
{
  transform: translateX(250%);
}
#closeFilter
{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Quest</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>



<div class="main">
 


<div class="filter">
 <button onclick="openMenu(this)" id="openFilter">filter</button>
 <div class="title">
  <h2>Filter</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="filter-body">
  <div><p href="#">Samsung</p><input type="checkbox" name="chk" data="Samsung" onclick="filter(this)" checked = "true"></div>
  <div><p href="#">Xiaomi</p><input type="checkbox" name="chk" onclick="filter(this)" data = "Xiaomi" checked = "true"></div>
  <div><p href="#">Apple</p><input type="checkbox" name="chk" onclick="filter(this)"data="Apple" checked = "true"></div>
  <div><p>RAM:</p></div>
  <div><p>4GB </p><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick = "ramFilter(this)" RAMS="4" checked="true"></div>
  <div><p>3GB </p><input type="checkbox" name=""onclick = "ramFilter(this)" RAMS="3" checked="true"></div>
  <div><p>6GB </p><input type="checkbox" name=""onclick = "ramFilter(this)" RAMS="6" checked="true"></div>
    <div><p>ROM:</p></div>
  <div><p>64GB </p><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick = "romFilter(this)" ROMS="64" checked="true"></div>
  <div><p>128GB</p><input type="checkbox" name=""onclick = "romFilter(this)" ROMS="128" checked="true"></div>
  <button onclick="closeMenu(this)" id="closeFilter">close Filter</button>
 </div>
 <div class="filter-footer">
  
 </div>

</div>


<div class="container">
 <div class="container-first-column" data="Samsung" id="Samsung">
  <div class="container-first-column-row" ram="4" rom = "64">
   <img src="a30.png">
   <h2>Samsung A30 4/64</h2>
   <p>Inch:6.4'</p>
   <p><img src="rezolution.png" class="icon">Rezolution: 2340x1080</p>
   <p>Processor: Exynos 7904</p>
   <p>Numbers of threads: 8</p>
   <p>Display: SUPER AMOLED</p>
   <p><img src="camera.png" class="icon">Camera: 16mp + 5mp</p>
   <p>Front Camera: 16mp</p>
   <p>Android: 9.0(Pie)</p>
   <button><img src="cart.png" class="icon">Buy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container-first-column-row"  ram="4" rom = "64">
   <img src="a50.jpg">
   <h2>Samsung A50 4/64</h2>
   <p>Inch:6.4'</p>
   <p><img src="rezolution.png" class="icon">Rezolution: 2340x1080</p>
   <p>Processor: Exynos 7904</p>
   <p>Numbers of threads: 8</p>
   <p>Display: SUPER AMOLED</p>
   <p><img src="camera.png" class="icon">Camera: 16mp + 5mp</p>
   <p>Front Camera: 16mp</p>
   <p>Android: 9.0(Pie)</p>
   <button><img src="cart.png" class="icon">Buy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container-first-column-row"  ram="6" rom = "128">
   <img src="a70.jpg">
   <h2>Samsung A70 6/128</h2>
   <p>Inch:6.4'</p>
   <p><img src="rezolution.png" class="icon">Rezolution: 2340x1080</p>
   <p>Processor: Exynos 7904</p>
   <p>Numbers of threads: 8</p>
   <p>Display: SUPER AMOLED</p>
   <p><img src="camera.png" class="icon">Camera: 16mp + 5mp</p>
   <p>Front Camera: 16mp</p>
   <p>Android: 9.0(Pie)</p>
   <button><img src="cart.png" class="icon">Buy</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-second-column" data="Xiaomi"  id="Xiaomi">
  <div class="container-second-column-row"  ram="4" rom = "128">
   <div><img src="note7.jpg"></div>
   <h2>Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 4/128</h2>
   <p>Inch:6.3'</p>
   <p><img src="rezolution.png" class="icon">Rezolution: 2340x1080</p>
   <p>Processor: Qualcomm Snapdragon 660</p>
   <p>Numbers of threads: 8</p>
   <p>Display: IPS (LTPS LCD)</p>
   <p><img src="camera.png" class="icon">Camera: 48mp + 5mp</p>
   <p>Front Camera: 13mp</p>
   <p>Android: 9.0(Pie)</p>
   <button><img src="cart.png" class="icon">Buy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container-second-column-row" ram="6" rom = "128">
   <div><img src="n8pro.jpg"></div>
   <h2>Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro 6/128</h2>
   <p>Inch:6.53'</p>
   <p><img src="icons/rezolution.png" class="icon">Rezolution: 2340x1080</p>
   <p>Processor:  MediaTek Helio G90T</p>
   <p>Numbers of threads: 8</p>
   <p>Display: IPS (LTPS LCD)</p>
   <p><img src="camera.png" class="icon">Camera: 64mp + 8mp + 2mp</p>
   <p>Front Camera: 13mp</p>
   <p>Android: 9.0(Pie)</p>
   <button><img src="cart.png" class="icon">Buy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container-second-column-row" ram="6" rom = "128">
   <div><img src="k20.jpg"></div>
   <h2>Xiaomi Redmi K20 6/128</h2>
   <p>Inch:6.53'</p>
   <p><img src="icons/rezolution.png" class="icon">Rezolution: 2340x1080</p>
   <p>Processor:  MediaTek Helio G90T</p>
   <p>Numbers of threads: 8</p>
   <p>Display: IPS (LTPS LCD)</p>
   <p><img src="camera.png" class="icon">Camera: 64mp + 8mp + 2mp</p>
   <p>Front Camera: 13mp</p>
   <p>Android: 9.0(Pie)</p>
   <button><img src="cart.png" class="icon">Buy</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-third-column" data="Apple"  id="Apple">
  <div class="container-third-column-row" ram="3" rom = "64">
   <div><img src="iphx.jpg"></div>
   <h2>Apple Iphone X 3/64</h2>
   <p>Inch:5.8'</p>
   <p><img src="rezolution.png" class="icon">Rezolution: 1242x2688</p>
   <p>Processor:  Apple A11</p>
   <p>Numbers of threads: 8</p>
   <p>Display: Super Retina</p>
   <p><img src="camera.png" class="icon">Camera: 12mp</p>
   <p>Front Camera: 7mp</p>
   <p>iOS 13.3</p>
   <button><img src="cart.png" class="icon">Buy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container-third-column-row" ram="3" rom = "64">
   <div><img src="iphxs.jpg"></div>
   <h2>Apple Iphone XS 3/64</h2>
   <p>Inch:5.8'</p>
   <p><img src="rezolution.png" class="icon">Rezolution: 1242x2688</p>
   <p>Processor:  Apple A11</p>
   <p>Numbers of threads: 8</p>
   <p>Display: Super Retina</p>
   <p><img src="camera.png" class="icon">Camera: 12mp</p>
   <p>Front Camera: 7mp</p>
   <p>iOS 13.3</p>
   <button><img src="cart.png" class="icon">Buy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container-third-column-row" ram="3" rom = "64">
   <div><img src="iphxsmax.png"></div>
   <h2>Apple Iphone XS Max 3/64</h2>
   <p>Inch:6.5'</p>
   <p><img src="rezolution.png" class="icon">Rezolution: 1242x2688</p>
   <p>Processor:  Apple A12</p>
   <p>Numbers of threads: 8</p>
   <p>Display: Super Retina</p>
   <p><img src="camera.png" class="icon">Camera: 12mp</p>
   <p>Front Camera: 7mp</p>
   <p>iOS 13.3</p>
   <button><img src="cart.png" class="icon">Buy</button>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>







</div>






<script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не используйте onclick в html коде, вытаскивайте элемент через js в переменную и там с ним работайте. Вместо того, чтобы задавать стиль элементу, вы можете просто менять его класс element.style.classList.toggle('active'). А в css коде вы напишите стили для этого элемента: element {display: none} element.active {display: flex} Если ваших стилей для элемента будет несколько, вам придётся городить element.style, использовать переключатель для класса очень удобно

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, _Не используйте onclick в html коде_ - почему?

Comment: @Grundy если использовать onclick в html, то нужно бегать по файлам туда-сюда, чтобы понять, а где этот элемент, как с ним связывались. Когда обраещься к элементу через js, сразу понятно, откуда он взялся

Comment: проблемы с отступами. Плохие названия переменных. Излишне большие функции (я бы написал тоже намного короче). Дублирование кода (туда же)

Comment: а зачем ты приложил html и css, если их не надо оценивать? Особенно css

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, вообще никакой связи не вижу :) что значит бегать по файлам? Поиском в любом случае придется пользоваться

Comment: @MikhailIonkin чтоб вы понимали что да как работает. спасибо, буду исправляться!